# How to make road follow curve smoother?

Tags: bezier-curves

How can I make road follow the curve smoother as seen in question "Why doesn't road follow the curve?"
[image: Screenshot:]

Comment: Did u subdivide the plane atleast 7-8 times

Comment: No, I forgot about it XD

Comment: Go to edit mode and subdivide the plane 7-8 times and then extrude it

Comment: subdivide horizontally, vertically or both?

Comment: horizontally but u can try both